# Why does shasum generate non-standard hashes?

Tags: terminal, bash

As far as I can tell, the shasum that ships with os x doesn't generate the hashes that it's supposed to.

```
$ echo "" | /usr/bin/shasum
adc83b19e793491b1c6ea0fd8b46cd9f32e592fc ?-
```

When I look up [empty string sha hash in wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SHA-1#Example_hashes) I see that I should expect to get

```
da39a3ee 5e6b4b0d 3255bfef 95601890 afd80709
```

My reading of the man page for shasum is that it defaults to sha 1. I get the same result even if I specify sha 1.

What's going on here?

ps Apologies for the bad tag. I can't create a tag of sha or shasum due to low reputation...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`shasum` is working fine but `echo ""` doesn't produce an empty string:

```
pse@Fourecks:~$ echo "" | od
0000000    000012                                                         
0000001
```

This works better:

```
pse@Fourecks:~$ echo -n "" | shasum
da39a3ee5e6b4b0d3255bfef95601890afd80709
```